# Opamp oscillator kick start

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator

We have this oscillator and for it to run the initial condition is Vout to be V+.

[image]

How is this done? Shouldn't it be equal to 0V from the schematic?

Comment: in reality the assumption is that imperfections in the parts and the supply voltage will kick start the circuit - at least thats my knowledge, corrections welcome

Comment: Yes - power switch-on transients will primarily determine the state at t=0.

Comment: It doesn't need Vout out to be any particular voltage for it to start.

Comment: Andy aka it does. If Vout is 0V then V+=0V and the capacitor won't begin charging.

Comment: @Se1fie If Vout is 0V that means the capacitor is already charged, and it will be discharging though Vout path. It will still oscillate.

Comment: sarthak Vout is never 0V.

Comment: No. Vout will be either V- or V+ but never (except instantaneously while switching) 0V.